# Mapping App-Scoped-Ids for apps pulling page posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

We run a platform that acts as a one-stop warehouse of user's interactions with a brand, both through apps (campaigns etc) and through the pages run by the brand. So far, the linking up of facebook users across apps and page-posts was simple - since facebook passed you global facebook ids.

With v2.0 of Graph API, and the migration to app-scoped-id, a brand can still connect the app-scoped-id from various app-authentications through the /ids_for_business api call. When User's log into the app, they are considered authenticated and hence the mapping between app-scoped-ids works.

For posts pulled from the Facebook pages through the API, the "users" are considered non-authenticated, and hence the mappings through /ids_for_business call skip the app_scoped_id listed to page-post-pulling-apps.

Is there a solution to map such users into their app-scoped-ids issued to other apps under the same business account?

Alternatively, is there any other way to reliably map such users across apps and page posts?

Answer (score 1):

Its not currently possible to map a user's ID across multiple apps where the user has not logged into each of the apps you're trying to map across.

The use case for the Business Mapping API it to identify the same use across the multiple apps your business owns - where the user has logged into those apps. For example, identifying which of your business's games the person plays.

The principle here is that a person's information is not aggregateable across apps unless the person has explicitly logged into those apps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Don't you think if a user makes a post or a comment on a page that is owned by the same business account, the business should have an ability to map that person to their apps/games activity?